# Equivalent of tf.assign in tensorflow 2.0 beta1?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I've installed the 2.0beta1 release of tensorflow but it seems that it has no assign attribute. Is there an equivalent to tf.assign() in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TensorFlow 2.0 `assign` is a method of the `tf.Variable` objects and no more a function of the `tensorflow` package.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(2)
a.assign(5)
assert a.numpy() == 5
```

Comment: So how to do `tf.assign(a, [1,2], validate_shape=False)` in TF2.x?

Comment: See also https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35667